# Pass All API Gateway Requests to one Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, strongloop

I am using Strong loop in AWS Lambda and i want to trigger it somehow. The only available option right now is APi Gateway. Is there a way to create one resource and pass all its requests to single lambda function?

I want to achieve something like this

```
/api/* --> Lambda Function
```

Does AWS support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported by API gateway proxy resource. You can create a special path parameter `{proxy+}` which represents any child resource of a parent API. The `ANY` method can be used to catch all http methods on that resource.

In your case, you need to create an api resource `/api` and under that, create a new proxy resource `{proxy+}`. If you are creating it through the AWS console, you just have to check the check box for the option **Configure as proxy resource** while creating the resource. When you get to the integration setup, select **Lambda Function Proxy** as your integration type, choose the region and select the lambda function you want to invoke.

This is described in detail in the API gateway docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-proxy-resource).